# Application Permissions Request Endlessly Redirects with IE

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, redirect, facebook-apps

This code works great for all browsers except Internet Explorer.

Basically when the redirect is sent to IE it just request the exact same URL again from my server, it just ignores the redirect.

Using the 3.1.1 code from Naitik Shah

Here's the code:

```
// $g_facebook is declared earlier and given app id and secret
$par[ 'scope' ] = array( 'publish_stream' , // publish to the user's stream
                                 'offline_access' , // access these functions when the user is offline
                                 // 'user_status'    , // get the user's latest status
                                 // 'read_stream'    , // read the user's stream
                                 'email'          , // provides the user's email address
                                 'user_groups'    , // provides the user's groups
                                 // 'sms'            , // send and receive txt w/ user
                                 'publish_actions', // publish scores and achievements
                                 );
header( 'Location: ' . $g_facebook->getLoginUrl( $par ) );
exit( );
```

Here's what happens on the wire (picked it up with tcpdump):

```
GET /fork HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: fbar.toolsteam.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=7f32d7e4acd63696bd8d0998913f608c; PHPSESSID=e30076106b21e40142397219283fd55f

HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Mon, 07 May 2012 07:36:12 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=a9f17a1119dc262bef693d2d39a15317; expires=Tue, 07-May-2013 07:36:12 GMT; path=/
Location: http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=336243633108439&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffbar.toolsteam.com%2Ffork&state=b52dd5dd08e0058e28ae8734f269cd77&scope=publish_stream%2Coffline_access%2Cemail%2Cuser_groups%2Cpublish_actions
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html
X-Cache: MISS from base
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from base:3128
Via: 1.1 base:3128 (squid/2.7.STABLE9)
Connection: keep-alive
```

When IE sees the 302 it just sends the original request again and again. It never follows the redirect to facebook.

As said before, Chrome and Firefox have no problems.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the request headers:

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=7f32d7e4acd63696bd8d0998913f608c; PHPSESSID=e30076106b21e40142397219283fd55f
```

There are two servers involved in this facebook auth, one is the originating website, the second is an intermediate server that negotiates the facebook permissions. The facebook server is a sub-domain of the primary site.

Turns out both of them were starting php sessions. The facebook server's cookie was at the sub-domain scope, the primary site's cookie was at the top-domain scope.

For whatever reason IE couldn't handle sending the same cookie twice on a request to the facebook server - it handled the transaction just fine but for whatever reason would just re-request the same URL and ignore the 302 redirect. IE is like that.

I switched the session variable name on the facebook server and the problem disappeared.